# Comparing a color range using either hex or decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, colors

I am extracting the main color from a picture, and then want to call a different function depending on whether it is red, blue, green, yellow, purple etc. (the more options I can have, the better). So what I would like to be able to do is:

```
if(color < maxColorValueRed && color > minColorValueRed) {
function1();
}
else {
if { .....
```

Where maxColorValue and minColorValue are either hexadecimal or decimal color values, and all the values between would count as the same rough color - so specify (roughly) the minimum and maximum red colors, for example.

So I have two questions:
1) can I compare hexadecimals? And how? It would make life easier if I could do it with this rather than decimal.
2) Anyone got a handy chart giving the color ranges? Ordinary charts (i.e. what I can find on google) are doing my head in . . . looking at them, I'm not even 100% sure I can specify a range like that?

Basically, I'm not entirely sure this is even doable this way - anyone have any suggestions for getting the same end result another way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How many "options" would be enough and can you tell us more about your use case?

Comment: It's an app that takes a photo and returns a poetry quotation, depending on the main color of the photo (and a few other factors, but those should be easier to compare . . .)

Comment: oops I meant a new line not "enter" :p I want (as a minimum) red, green, blue, yellow, purple, black, white . . . orange wouldn't hurt either I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer #1. You can compare hexadecimal number by converting it to base of 10. Like this

```
var h1 = "FFFF00", h2 = "FFFF01";

if (parseInt("0x" + h1, 16) < parseInt("0x" + h2, 16) ){
    console.log("H1 is smaller than H2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) can I compare hexadecimals? And how? It would make life easier if I
>   could do it with this rather than decimal.

Yes and no. The selection structure would be very long, if you want to have a wide range of color selection, i would suggest to compare by RGB values. You can use it with the [Color class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) in java API. Here below is a conversion method to RGB and returns the Color object.

```
// color string is of type "#FFFFFF"
private Color hexToColor(String hex) {
    return new Color(
        Integer.valueOf(hex.substring(1,3), 16),
        Integer.valueOf(hex.substring(3,5), 16),
        Integer.valueOf(hex.substring(5,7), 16));
}
```

Ofc you have to control first if it's a valid hex string.
then comparing is way easier with only comparing the color class with the predefined static colors like Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN in a structure. (also provided in the class API here above)